# How to convert number value into numeral word?

Tags: abap

I am trying to check if a certain number, e.g. 7845, has any thousands, hundred, or tens, e.g. 7845 has 7 times thousands, 8 times hundreds, 4 times tens.

The program is supposed to then convert the amount of times to a string:

```
IF ( DMBTR MOD 10000000 ) LE 9.
    DMBTR / 10000000 = lv_tenmillions.
    lv_tenmillions_check = lv_tenmillions MOD 1.
    
    IF lv_tenmillions_check > 0.
     "Convert
   ENDIF.
   
   IF lv_tenmillions_check < 0.
     "ZERO
   ENDIF.
  ENDIF.
```

The code that I have written would check for tenmillions, thus would check if the MOD of a value with 10000000 is less equal to 9. Is there any function or code that is used in abap to convert the number into letters?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: You want to convert numbers to text, like 123 => One hundred twenty-three?

Comment: @JózsefSzikszai Yes, that is exactly what I want to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use function module SPELL_AMOUNT:

```
DATA: lv_spell TYPE spell.

CALL FUNCTION 'SPELL_AMOUNT'
  EXPORTING
    amount    = 123
*   CURRENCY  = ' '
*   FILLER    = ' '
*   LANGUAGE  = SY-LANGU
  IMPORTING
    in_words  = lv_spell
  EXCEPTIONS
    not_found = 1
    too_large = 2
    OTHERS    = 3.
```

lv_spell-word contains what you need.

Answer (score 2):

use the functional module SPELL_AMOUNT. Or copy it and go to town.

```
REPORT ZQUICK.
PARAMETERS p_amt type  p LENGTH 8 .
data l_in_words type spell.


call function 'SPELL_AMOUNT'
  EXPORTING
     amount    = p_amt        " Amount/Number to Be Spelled Out
*    currency  = space    " Currency for Amounts, Blank for Numbers
*    filler    = space    " Filler for Padding the Output Field
*    language  = SY-LANGU " Language Indicator
 IMPORTING
     in_words  = l_in_words. " 

write : l_in_words-word.
```